# What's the right workaround to send DIFFERENT messages to DIFFERENT recipients in PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send an email to multiple different BCC recipients.
Every recipient gets an identical text body BUT, he also needs to receive his own individual email in it.

I'm looping through a JSON to add emails with the $mail->addBCC() function.
And I need that the $body that is sent to every individual user will contain his own individual address.

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'src/Exception.php';
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';

//*** -> $allUsers is a JSON

function sendemails_ex($allUsers, $subject, $body)
{
            $emailFrom = "noreply@slandergold.com";
            $emailFromName = "slandergold.com";

            if ($allUsers=="" || $subject=="" || $body=="")
            {
                exit();
            }

            $smtpUsername = "abcdKLARK"; 
            $smtpPassword = "1t%y$R5$4";

            $mail = new PHPMailer;

            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

            $mail->isSMTP(); 
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; 
            $mail->Host = "mail.slandergold.com";

            $mail->Port = 26; //587; // TLS only
            $mail->SMTPSecure = false; //'tls'; // ssl is depracated
            $mail->SMTPAuth = false; //true;
            $mail->Username = $smtpUsername;
            $mail->Password = $smtpPassword;

            $mail->setFrom($emailFrom, $emailFromName);

            $arr = json_decode($allUsers,true);

            foreach($arr as $item) 
            { 
                $mail->addBCC($item['Email'], $item['Fullname']);
            }

            $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
            $mail->Subject = $subject;

            // ***********
            // is there a way to make it 
            // so that every individual BCC recipient 
            // will get a body with the individual addition of: 
            // $userEmail = ?
            // $body."<br />This is your email: ".$userEmail;
            // ***********

            $mail->msgHTML($body);

            $mail->AltBody = 'HTML messaging not supported';

            if(!$mail->send())
            {
                echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Message sent!";
            }
}
```

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: No I don't think it's possible, BCC is not a copy of the email it's just a blind forward Where the other recipients cannot see the included emails

Comment: BCC are only hidden copies to others, A workaround is, to send the original mail without BCC, and then a copy of the mail + additional personal info to each BCC candidate.

Comment: Who would -1 my question instead of helping me find a workaround for the issue? LAME!
Thanx @Wiimm so I should simply create a lot of instances of this procedure? a single call to this function for every separate email, using addAddress() only once every time?

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, you can’t send different emails to different recipients using BCC. You need to send each message individually, and the definitive way to do that is provided in [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps). There are also notes in the project wiki about how to send to lists efficiently.

Comment: Thank you, I read it indeed. I thought that by sending a single time is more efficient while sending tens of emails with different instances is less effective on my mail server

Comment: Yes it is, but it comes at the cost of not being able to send different messages to each recipient. It also presents problems if you want to have per-user content such as unsubscribe links. It's also not that inefficient – you can send hundreds of messages per second when sending through a local mail server using keepalive.